# Are Their Any Web Based Visual Drag and Drop SQL Builders Available (React, Vue, Angular, jQuery, .Net etc)?

Tags: web-apps, library, javascript, software-development, web-development

I am looking for a visual SQL editor that we can embed into our web application. We would like an drag and drop interface similar to the ones in:

- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
- Microsoft Access
- Devart SQL
- MySQL Workbench
- SAP Crystal Reports
- dbForce Query Builder

Ideally the tool can learn the database schema from the connected data source, allow the user to select tables, columns, create where clauses, create joins, apply functions, group, aggregate, sort, edit the SQL if needed, and hopefully preview the data. Once the user has saved the query the tool should be able to pass us back the SQL SELECT statement the user has created and optionally a JSON of the visual layout. We should be able to pass that SQL statement and/or JSON layout back to the tool so the user can edit the statement later on.

I have looked at [ActiveQueryBuilder.com](https://www.ActiveQueryBuilder.com) but I am looking for other options as well. At a minimum it needs to support SQLServer but ideally I would like it to support other database platforms as well like MySQL. We would like an open source library if one exists but are not apposed to using a commercial library. Ideally we would prefer a React or jQuery application but are open to other solutions as well such as .NET solutions. I have not found very many web based designers available. Please note the web application will run locally to the data source so ideally we need something that can be hosted locally and does not use a cloud service.

Thank you.